# Why didn't Tony actually try Thor's fingerprint?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, mjolnir

In *Age of Ultron*, Tony says:

> Tony Stark: It's biometrics, right? Like a security code? "Whoever is carrying Thor's fingerprints" is, I think, the literal translation.
>
> Thor: Yes, well that's a very, very interesting theory. I have a simpler one: You're all not worthy.

Granted, Ultron bursts in at this point and wreaks some havoc, but Tony's had plenty of access to the hammer before and will probably have more in the future.

I don't imagine it would take much for someone like Tony to be able to replicate Thor's fingerprints, or even an iris scan, or whatever he needs.

Obviously, in the comics, it's literally a magic enchantment on Mjolnir, so this just wouldn't work, but in the MCU, even the "Magic" in **Doctor Strange** isn't just magic, it's some kind of energy manipulation via extra-dimensional technology.

Though even if having his fingerprint isn't enough to wield Mjolnir, it strikes me as odd that Tony hasn't even tried.

So, given all that, why hasn't Tony Stark tried to use Thor's fingerprint to lift Thor's hammer?

Comment: They're just drinking and messing around. Given enough time or actual need, I'm sure he might actually try it. But why bother otherwise? Tony's got his own weapons and has no real need or reason to wield Mjolnir.

Comment: It's notable that the same movie proves it must not be just a fingerprint, because (the Good) Ultron picks it up later and he certainly doesn't have any of the same biometrics as Thor.

Comment: Well, once Thor found out what Tony was up to, he'd deliver a fingerprint sample via slap upside the head.

Comment: Also, Tony's smart enough to know that "fingerprints" are an extremely low-tech and easily hackable method of biometrics sensor when used alone and that 'magic' is extremely high tech. While he might legitimately think it was biometric in nature, he'd have it assume that it relied on something far more robust given even today we have biometrics that not only check fingerprints but also the unique thermal signature of capillaries under the skin. He was just 'dumbing it down' for an audience.  Also, this line of thinking is how you get [Clor](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ragnarok_(Earth-616)).

Comment: Yeah, I think Tony is just trash talking here. He must know it's not really fingerprints (I mean, the hammer comes to Thor when he summons it, that can't be finger print activated). It probably does make sense for him to really figure it out though, in the same way he creates the Hulkbuster, or that Batman (I know, crossing the streams, sorry!) keeps a stash of Kryptonite. Y'know... just in case.

Comment: "it's some kind of energy manipulation via extra-dimensional technology." sufficiently-advanced technology, indistinguishable, etc.

Comment: Worth noting that Thor himself couldn't lift the hammer for a good chunk of his first movie, until he proved himself worthy.  I seem to recall that took a lot more than washing his hands.

Comment: All of these comments make really good points. Also, Cap did actually manage to move it a bit. And when Quiksilver tried to snatch it out the air it just took him with it, so it clearly doesn't even need a surface to be able to prevent somebody using it. There's a lot of weird Mjolnir stuff that probably won't ever get explained. I just wanted to know why Tony hadn't even thought about trying, but him being clever enough to know that won't work, plus being too busy with PTSD and "Peace in our time" to get a good look at the hammer in a lab environment are pretty compelling arguments.

Comment: How do you know that he didn't try it? BTW, Vision didn't have Thor's fingerprints and yet he was able to lift the hammer.

Answer (score 1):

tony is arrogant yes but I think he knows when he's beat. He knows asguardians will be using much more sophisticated bio-metrics than he'll be able to replicate. I think it was more of a jab at thors' "silly superstitions".

also he would need to GET those fingerprints (probably a complete set, in high definition meaning no taking it from surfaces) from thor. While tony is cocky he's not gunna go up to the temperamental princess and as him for fingerprints.

possibly he will at some-point and is just planning it out atm.

Answer (score -2):

Actually it doesn't work on this concept fingerprint concept. Thor is a mythological character of MCU mythological dosen't considers technology they are generally magic, supernatural powers and all.. So basically thor's hammer lifting dosen't works on fingerprint because even in THOR(2011) thor couldn't lift his hammer when he was abondent to earth then when at last of the movie when he gave away all his ego and attitude finally he became worthy of it. Similarly vision was worthy so he could lift the hammer and in the comics BETA-RAY BILL also lifted it.

So it dosen't work in that way.

Comment: This explains why it is not a valid theory, but the question was about why Stark didn't try.

Comment: sorry to disappoint you, I  somehow mis understood the question. I provided all the information I had. sorry for inconvenience.